# Django login form in bootstrap popup

Tags: python, ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

Using django 1.5 + twitter bootstrap.

Have a popup dropdown (bootstrap) login form on every page.
Authentificating with right credentials working good.
Now, my problem - need to add error message on wrong credentials on the same page, without page reloading. It can be a modal window, or better if it would be just a text in the same popup window. Dunno how to do that, without redirect/reload.

Some code:

### views.py:

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
            else:
                return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        return render_to_response('/', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    'accounts.views',
    url(r'^signup/$', 'AccountRegistration'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'LoginRequest'),
    url(r'^logout/$', 'LogoutRequest'),
)
```

### forms.py:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        email = forms.CharField(label=(u'Email'), max_length=30)
        password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Pass'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), max_length=30)
```

### Fragment of template with my popup:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="/profile/">{{ user }}</a></li>
    <li>
        <form style="margin:0;" action='/logout/' method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-link" style="color:#777777;" /></li>
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ current_path }}" />
        </form>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
            <form action='/login/' method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {% if form.errors %}
                    {{ form.errors}}
                {% endif %}
                <label for="id_email">Login:</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email">
                <br />
                <label for="id_password">Pass:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password">
                <br />
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" />
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ current_path }}" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a page to reload you'll have to submit with [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) and do something on it's return method.